# Finding $\mathbf{10}\otimes \mathbf{8}\otimes \mathbf{8}\otimes \mathbf{8}$ in $SU(3)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, physics, young-tableaux

I know that in $SU(3)$
$$\mathbf{8}\otimes \mathbf{8} = \mathbf{27}+\mathbf{10}+\mathbf{\bar{10}}+\mathbf{8}+\mathbf{8}+\mathbf{1}. $$

How can one use this to compute $$\mathbf{10}\otimes \mathbf{8}\otimes \mathbf{8}\otimes \mathbf{8}?$$

Can one start with simplifying (dropping the bold notation)

$$\tag{1} \mathbf{10}\otimes \mathbf{8}\otimes \mathbf{8} = 10\otimes27
\\
+10\otimes10
\\+10\otimes\bar{10}
\\+10\otimes8
\\+10\otimes8
\\+10\otimes1?$$

Is $(1)$ even ok?

Comment: Could you give a little context, or at least definitions? To the best of my knowledge, 10 and 8 are integers, not three-by-three unitary matrices.

Comment: @Neal see the [quark model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_model)

Comment: Yes, tensor products of reps distribute over sums of reps, so (1) is ok.  I'm not sure how, e.g.  $10\otimes 27$ decomposes.

Comment: Can one reduce 10x1? I strongly suspect no,but I have to ask.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks!

Comment: this is a $5120$ dimensional representation!

Comment: That's right @johnmangual, hopefully the left hand side should add up to that.

Comment: It is also worth noting that this can be computed using a Mathematica package like LieART (https://lieart.hepforge.org/)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a portion of the answer.  All of these calculations are coming from [here](http://wwwmathlabo.univ-poitiers.fr/~maavl/LiE/form.html).

In terms of that website, we think of $SU(3)$ as $A_2$.  Then, the $10$ dim rep has heighest weight $(3,0)$ in their notation (and the $\overline{10}$ has heighest weight $(0,3)$).  The $27$ d rep is $(2,2)$.  The notation the website uses is $X[3,0]$, $X[0,3]$, or $X[2,2]$ respectively.

According to that website, we have

$$10\otimes 27 = 1X[5,2] +1X[3,3] +1X[4,1] +1X[1,4] +1X[2,2] +1X[3,0] +1X[0,3] +1X[1,1],$$ or in your notation,

$$10\otimes 27 = 81 + 64 + 35 + \overline{35} + 27 + 10 + \overline{10} + 8$$

A small disclaimer:  in $SU(3)$, the dimension of a representation does *not* determine the representation, even discounting conjugate representations.  For example, $X[2,1]$, $X[4,0]$, $X[1,2]$, and $X[0,4]$ are each distinct irreducible $15$ dimensional representations.  So, notation like $8$, $10$, $\overline{10}$, while unambiguous, would be ambiguous applied to the number $15$.

Comment: To answer your comment, yes, $10\otimes 1 = 10$.  Also, I'm not sure what size inputs the program I linked to can handle (I think it can only handle single digit highest weights).

Comment: Great answer @Jason DeVito. Where did you find the dictionary for that website's notation?

Comment: @LoveLearning:  I wish I had a nice answer.  I used the website quite a bit about 6-7 years ago when trying to figure out some stuff for my thesis, and I remember a lot of how it worked from then.  The $A_2 \iff SU(3)$ notation is fairly standard (see classification of simple Lie algebras), and the recognition that, e.g., $X[3,0]\iff 10$ came from plugging things into their "dimension of a module" option, and noting that dimension $10$ only occurred for $X[3,0]$ and $X[0,3]$.

Comment: Oh ok. I guess that the numbers p,q in X[p,q] stands for the Dynkin coefficients, but like I said it would be nice to have a dictionary.

Comment: btw as you mentioned, one can use that website's function "Dimension of a module" to find out e.g. what X[2,1] stands for wrt my notation. Thanks.

Comment: but how did you know to distinguish between X[4,1] and X[1,4]? Both are of dimension 35. So which one is barred?

Comment: Well, I kind of cheated.  I don't know your notation well enough to say which one is barred, so in my head, I defined $X[4,1] = 35$.  In terms of the Dynkin indices, it then follows that $X[1,4] = \overline{35}$.  (I'm actually heading to lunch, then class, so I won't be able to respond for another 4 hours or so...)

Comment: Aaa'it, cheers.

Comment: do you know if there is a resolution of the ambiguity issue?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  The only notation I've ever used is by labeling the nodes in the Dynkin diagram by natural numbers, or variations on that.

Comment: OK comments must be at least 15