# Simplifying a direct sum $\mathbf{3}\oplus\mathbf{3}\oplus\mathbf{2}$ etc

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, direct-sum, direct-product, young-tableaux

In particle physics, one often uses the dimensionality of the irrep to label the irrep (apparently this is not a very good idea since [the dimension does not unambiguously determine the rep.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1117192/110467)). What are the rules one can use to simplify calculations involving direct sums. I have this one example of a direct product that on the right hand side contains many repeating terms:

For instance, suppose you have something like $D = 10\otimes 8 \oplus 10\otimes 8.$
If I have done my calculations right one should get for each term in $SU(3)$

$$\mathbf{10}\otimes \mathbf{8} = \mathbf{35}+\mathbf{27}+\mathbf{10}+\mathbf{8}$$ so that (dropping the bold notation) 
$$\tag{1}10\otimes 8\oplus 10\otimes 8 = 35\oplus27\oplus10\oplus8\oplus 35\oplus27\oplus10\oplus8. $$

Is there a way to simplify the right hand side of equation $(1)$ in the sense of simply writing e.g. $$\mathbf{35}\oplus\mathbf{35}\oplus\mathbf{35} = 3\cdot \mathbf{35}$$ where $3\in \mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: How do you define directs sums / tensor products of numbers?

Comment: I've updated the answer @MarcvanLeeuwen

Comment: You can simplify it just as you did, but you have to be very careful that you keep bold/nonbold stuff straight.  Also, your original calculation could have simplified to $2(\mathbf{10}\otimes \mathbf{8})$.

Comment: Yeah I suspected that.